# Yii2 show active() records on a new index page of the same controller

Tags: yii2

I don't even know how to define my question, so I couldn't really search for an answer, so it would be appreciated if you could point me to the right direction.
I have a model a view and a controller. Normally if I'm calling index, I'm getting all records. That works fine. Now I would like to query from the DB only the *active()* records. So I would like to see on a new index page only the active records. Where do I have to define this? Of course, the function itself is already defined in ModelQuery. But in Controller, I have to create a new function, in order to be able to call a new view.

```
public function actionIndex2() {
    $searchModel = new ModelSearch;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($_GET);
    ...
    return $this->render('index2', [
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    ]);
}
```

I have tried to add `->active()` to all possible places here but no luck. I can't mess with ModelSearch, because then I would ruin basic index site functionality also. It's clear that I can use it when I'm doing so: `Order::find()->active()`, but now it's not the case. Do I have to create a new ModelSearch also? I hope it's not necessary. Many thanks!

Comment: you mean that you need  a page like the view  form/actionView but with a gridview instead of viewDetail ???    or something  other

Comment: I need a new **index** page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So officially you have to add your ActiveQueries to the search method of your ModelSearch.

```
public function search($params) {
    $query = Model::find()->activeQuery1()->activeQuery2();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        ...
```

or

```
public function search($params) {
    $query = Model::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query->activeQuery1()->activeQuery2(),
        ...
```

This means you have to create a new ModelSearch or a new search method in ModelSearch as many times as many combinations of ActiveQueries you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want filter by $id  eg  in your url /index2?id=10) you could try this way

```
  public function actionIndex2($id) {
      $searchModel = new ModelSearch;
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
      $dataProvider->query->
                  andWhere(['id' => $id]);  
      ...
      return $this->render('index2', [
                  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                  'searchModel' => $searchModel,
      ]);
  }
```

Comment: seems to be working: `$dataProvider->query->active();` Many thanks!

Comment: the problem is, this way basic filtering in grid is not functioning